# insufficient authorization to access external CSV files in sas studio

Tags: sas

Here is the code.

```
data test;
    infile '/folders/myfolders/smile.txt';
run;



ods csvall file='c:\test.cvs'; 
  proc print data=WORK.ONE;
     var Name Score Grade;
     by IdNumber;
  run; 
  ods csvall close;
```

The first data step runs well. The main issue is with the ods part. I got the insufficient authorization to access the csv file error in logs. Could anyone tell me why? Many thanks for your time and attention.

**EDIT**: So sorry for the mistake. For the second block of the code, that is actually this:

```
ods csvall file='/folders/myfolders/test.csv'; 
      proc print data=WORK.ONE;
         var Name Score Grade;
         by IdNumber;
      run; 
      ods csvall close;
```

Comment: Are you on a server or your own machine? Is SAS local or remote?

Comment: Is it really `.cvs` and not `.csv`?  And is this a SAS Studio with University Edition, or connected to a full install of local SAS or a remote server?

Comment: This is a sas studio with university edition.

Comment: On a server. SAS is remote.

Comment: @Lucy please post the full log from the submitted code, including the import.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, code you submit in SAS Studio is run on the server to which you're connected.

The first datastep reads from a (Unix) server path (forward slashes to delimit folders). The second block of code is trying to write out to a Windows drive (drive letter and backslash delimiters), but as the code is running on the Unix server, it knows nothing of your local (Windows) environment.

Comment: What he said. Change the path to '/folders/myfolders/test.csv' and it should work.